# How to rename only user on Ubuntu Server 14.04 ?

Tags: server

I wish to rename 'user1' to 'worker' on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I tried various answers on similar threads. But couldnt do it as the only option I had was to log into user1 and use the usermod command. But I cant kill the bash.

P.S. - I am new to this Ubuntu Universe.

Comment: Add a temporary admin user, log out of your current account, log in as temporary admin, change name of your old account, log out of temporary admin and back in as your old account with new name, delete the temporary admin account.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to create another user, add him to the sudoers file, log out, and login as the new user. Then, change your username, and delete the temporary user.

EDIT: Whoops, someone already commented that.